# Bootstrap tabbable btn-toolbar not toggling off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap to create a dropdown toggle that allows the user to hide/unhide certain div sections. The code is seen below:

```
<div class="tabbable">
   <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle input-large" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
               Select an Area by:
             <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Parish">Parish</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Area">MLS Area</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#City">City</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Zip">Zip</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  <!-- /btn-group -->
   </div>  <!-- /btn-toolbar -->

   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="Parish">
        Parish
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="Area">
            Area
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="City">
            City
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="Zip">
            Zip
      </div>
   </div>
```

It works (kind of), except for the fact that after selecting an option the first time, it never toggles off after selecting a new item. It also does not allow me to go back to an item that has already been selected. I have searched everywhere and used the web console in Firefox to debug, but do not see what the problem is. This happens in Chrome and IE too.

I have created a Bootstrap snippet that demonstrates the behavior here: http://bootply.com/102355

I would appreciate any help. Am I trying to do something with bootstrap that just can't be done yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you've solved this, but here it is how I would do it using jQuery (I don't know bootstrap):

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
    DeselectCurrent();
});


var DeselectCurrent = function() {
    jQuery('.dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
        var attr = jQuery(this).attr('class');            

        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    });
};
```

Here it's a working example: http://bootply.com/102465

By the way, in my example I named my function `DeselectCurrent`... It would make more sense if you named it `DeselectPrevious`.

Just a side note, I don't see in your markup an id with a value of `myTab` (like you are referencing it here `$('#myTab a').click(function (e)`) but I am assuming that's how you target your tabs in twitter-bootstrap...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. That did work. Of course, I had to add your script after the call to the jquery library (which makes sense). I still do not understand why the bootstrap class is not working, but I am still learning about Bootstrap and jQuery in general. If I figure out why (which is entirely likely since I hate not knowing why something is the way it is), I will follow-up with another comment here. Thanks again for getting me past that hump.